# Why I get an error on windows.navigation?

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
private void rectangle2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Jobsearch.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));    
}
```

I have taken a button in windowsphonecontrol page.xaml i want when i click on that button go to another page but i am getting an error i.e.:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)'

Why?

Answer (score 2):

[`NavigationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a `static` class and [`Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a `static` method.

You *can't* call this method without an instance of `NavigationService` class. You need to create an instance of `NavigationService` class and call it's `Navigate` method with `new Uri("/Jobsearch.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)` parameter.

As error message says;

> **An object reference is required** for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

```
private void rectangle2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Jobsearch.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));              
}
```

Comment: Accordering to your code i have written but this time i get an error system.windows.navigation.navigationservice has no constructor

Comment: @sandeepkumar Updated. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an instance of `NavigationService` because `Navigate` is not a static method. Try

```
private void rectangle2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService Navserv = new NavigationService();
    Navserv.Navigate(new Uri("/Jobsearch.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));               
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A static method is one that can be called without instantiating an object:

```
YourClass.YourStaticMethod();
```

A non-static method acts on the object you call it from:

```
YourClass yourObject = new YourClass(); // creating an instance
yourObject.YourNonStaticMethod(); // Applies only to yourObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Another factor for this is that you need to have a frame tag inside your MainWindow as a container for your view.

```
  <Frame x:Name="frame"/>
```

then instantiate navigationService in your MainWindow constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ApplicationHelper.NavigationService = frame.NavigationService;
}
```

then call the Navigate() inside your click function.

```
private void Navigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  YourView view = new YourView ();
  frmToDoList.Navigate(view);
}
```